# perl6 io::socket::inet how to set timeout for socket?

Tags: raku

```
my $c = IO::Socket::INET.new(:host<localhost>, :port(80));
$c.print: 'Test';
say $c.recv;
```

how can i set timeout for IO::Socket::INET  recv?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the timeout example in the [`Promise.anyof` doc](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/anyof).

(See also [Concurrent::Progress](https://github.com/jnthn/p6-concurrent-progress) for the more general case of tracking progress.)